# Why is fread() taking sooo long? (R 4.0.3)

Tags: r, optimization, import, data.table

I used to use `data.table`'s `fread()` almost exclusively when importing data up to 3.6, suddenly `fread()` is now taking MUCH (1hr+, used to take about 10 mins) longer to import datasets that are similar in size and nature to the ones I was opening a few months ago. Does anyone know why this is happening? I love `data.table` and want to continue to use it, so `data.table` solutions would be great.

Also, I am not 100% sure that this is exclusively of R 4.0, but I just cant think of any other reason. I am running R on a reasonably old server (Windows Server 2008 Enterprise) so that might also have something to do with it (even though as I said it worked wonderfully a couple months ago).

EDIT: CPU utilization is under 15% overall and there are no cores under any sustained load.

EDIT2: Reproducibility:

The database is 40GB (server has 300GB+ of RAM) I am open to suggestions as to how I can make this reproducible here. I am not doing anything else on my code this is the full extent of my script so far:

```
library(data.table)
data <- fread("mydata.csv")
```

When first loading `data.table` the console says `data.table 1.13.2 using 12 threads ...`

Comment: Please be specific. Otherwise there is no way we can help you. Please define a reproducible example. What is the text file? How large is the file? Are you running `fread` in an empty R session? Any non-default args with `fread`? Can you reproduce in older environment? Mention all OS and `data.table` version. *sooo long* is not a helpful descriptor. Is it 5 mins or 15 mins longer? How long ago did you use 3.6? I see you use plural *datasets* for a general sense of slower timing. Can you actually measure timings and reproduce slowness *each* time for *all* datasets?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have included the suggestions you mention I will give more exact timings very soon, but for that I have to re load multiple data sets on both new and old R versions (which takes time). For now please take me on my word that there has recently been a multiple-fold increase on how long it takes to import a dataset.

Comment: Read the help with `?setDTthreads` and see if setting it to `setDTthreads(0)` will help. Cran has restrictions in place on default threads (2).

Comment: It may be good to post to the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues) with number of columns and column types. You can attempt to make it reproducible with ```n = 100; tmp = tempfile(); fwrite(data.table(sample(n)), tmp); fread(tmp);``` with it scaled with more what your dataset looks like.

Comment: Provide verbose output of fread in old and new environment

Comment: Wow! thanks to everybody for the responses these are all great suggestions I'll make sure to implement them all and post the results.

Comment: please include number of columns & column types, as well as the verbose output as suggested. it may not lead to a solution but it can help diagnose the problem